# Debugging SQL statement of SSIS SQL task to insert range of date

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'm trying to insert range of date into a date dimensional table using SQL task, and passing through parameters of BeginDate / EndDate to it. However, if I try to execute the package, there are no data inserted in the dimensional table, but the package executes fine.

How do I go about getting the SQL statement of the SQL task, so I can identify the problem?

**I'm using 02/02/2014 and 02/02/2015 for BeginDate and EndDate respectively.**

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Loads a Date Dimension                                                    */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

-- A few notes, this code does nothing to the existing table, no deletes
-- are triggered before hand. Because the DateKey is uniquely indexed,
-- it will simply produce errors if you attempt to insert duplicates.
-- You can however adjust the Begin/End dates and rerun to safely add
-- new dates to the table every year.
--
-- If the begin date is after the end date, no errors occur but nothing
-- happens as the while loop never executes.

SET NOCOUNT ON -- turn off all the 1 row inserted messages

-- Hold our dates
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME

-- Holds a flag so we can determine if the date is the last day of month
DECLARE @LastDayOfMon CHAR(1)

-- Number of months to add to the date to get the current Fiscal date
DECLARE @FiscalYearMonthsOffset INT   

-- These two counters are used in our loop.
DECLARE @DateCounter DATETIME    --Current date in loop
DECLARE @FiscalCounter DATETIME  --Fiscal Year Date in loop

-- Set the date to start populating and end populating
SET @BeginDate = ?
SET @EndDate = ?

-- Set this to the number of months to add to the current date to the
-- beginning get of the Fiscal year. For example, if the Fiscal year
-- begins July 1, put a 6 there.
-- Negative values are also allowed, thus if your 2010 Fiscal year
-- begins in July of 2009, put a -6.
SET @FiscalYearMonthsOffset = 6

-- Start the counter at the begin date
SET @DateCounter = @BeginDate

WHILE @DateCounter <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
            -- Calculate the current Fiscal date as an offset of
            -- the current date in the loop
            SET @FiscalCounter = DATEADD(m, @FiscalYearMonthsOffset, @DateCounter)

            -- Set value for IsLastDayOfMonth
            IF MONTH(@DateCounter) = MONTH(DATEADD(d, 1, @DateCounter))
               SET @LastDayOfMon = 'N'
            ELSE
               SET @LastDayOfMon = 'Y'  

            -- add a record into the date dimension table for this date
            INSERT  INTO [dbo].[DimDate]
                    (
                      [DimDateID]
                    , [DimFullDate]
                    , [DimDateName]
                    , [DimDateNameUS]
                    , [DimDateNameEU]
                    , [DimDayOfWeek]
                    , [DimDayNameOfWeek]
                    , [DimDayOfMonth]
                    , [DimDayOfYear]
                    , [DimWeekdayWeekend]
                    , [DimWeekOfYear]
                    , [DimMonthName]
                    , [DimMonthOfYear]
                    , [DimIsLastDayOfMonth]
                    , [DimCalendarQuarter]
                    , [DimCalendarYear]
                    , [DimCalendarYearMonth]
                    , [DimCalendarYearQtr]
                    , [DimFiscalMonthOfYear]
                    , [DimFiscalQuarter]
                    , [DimFiscalYear]
                    , [DimFiscalYearMonth]
                    , [DimFiscalYearQtr]
                    )
            VALUES  (
                      ( YEAR(@DateCounter) * 10000 ) + ( MONTH(@DateCounter)
                                                         * 100 )
                      + DAY(@DateCounter)  --DateKey
                    , @DateCounter -- FullDate
                    , CAST(YEAR(@DateCounter) AS CHAR(4)) + '/'
                      + RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(mm, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2) + '/'
                      + RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(dd, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2) --DateName
                    , RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(mm, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2) + '/'
                      + RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(dd, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2)  + '/'
                      + CAST(YEAR(@DateCounter) AS CHAR(4))--DateName
                    , RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(dd, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2) + '/'
                      + RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(mm, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2)  + '/'
                      + CAST(YEAR(@DateCounter) AS CHAR(4))--DateName
                    , DATEPART(dw, @DateCounter) --DayOfWeek
                    , DATENAME(dw, @DateCounter) --DayNameOfWeek
                    , DATENAME(dd, @DateCounter) --DayOfMonth
                    , DATENAME(dy, @DateCounter) --DayOfYear
                    , CASE DATENAME(dw, @DateCounter)
                        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 'Weekend'
                        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 'Weekend'
                        ELSE 'Weekday'
                      END --WeekdayWeekend
                    , DATENAME(ww, @DateCounter) --WeekOfYear
                    , DATENAME(mm, @DateCounter) --MonthName
                    , MONTH(@DateCounter) --MonthOfYear
                    , @LastDayOfMon --IsLastDayOfMonth
                    , DATENAME(qq, @DateCounter) --CalendarQuarter
                    , YEAR(@DateCounter) --CalendarYear
                    , CAST(YEAR(@DateCounter) AS CHAR(4)) + '-'
                      + RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(mm, @DateCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2) --CalendarYearMonth
                    , CAST(YEAR(@DateCounter) AS CHAR(4)) + 'Q' + DATENAME(qq, @DateCounter) --CalendarYearQtr
                    , MONTH(@FiscalCounter) --[FiscalMonthOfYear]
                    , DATENAME(qq, @FiscalCounter) --[FiscalQuarter]
                    , YEAR(@FiscalCounter) --[FiscalYear]
                    , CAST(YEAR(@FiscalCounter) AS CHAR(4)) + '-'
                      + RIGHT('00' + RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(mm, @FiscalCounter) AS CHAR(2))), 2) --[FiscalYearMonth]
                    , CAST(YEAR(@FiscalCounter) AS CHAR(4)) + 'Q' + DATENAME(qq, @FiscalCounter) --[FiscalYearQtr]
                    )

            -- Increment the date counter for next pass thru the loop
            SET @DateCounter = DATEADD(d, 1, @DateCounter)
      END

SET NOCOUNT ON -- turn the annoying messages back on

-- Select all rows inserted for the final year as a sanity check
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[DimDate]
WHERE DimDateID > (YEAR(@EndDate) * 10000)
```

**Here is the create table SQL**

```
/* Create table dbo.DimDate */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimDate]
       ( [DimDateID] BIGINT NOT NULL
       , [DimFullDate] DATETIME NULL
       , [DimDateName] CHAR(11) NULL
       , [DimDateNameUS] CHAR(11) NULL   --US Date FORMAT, MM/DD/YYYY
       , [DimDateNameEU] CHAR(11) NULL   --European Union Date Format DD/MM/YYYY
       , [DimDayOfWeek] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimDayNameOfWeek] CHAR(10) NULL
       , [DimDayOfMonth] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimDayOfYear] SMALLINT NULL
       , [DimWeekdayWeekend] CHAR(7) NULL
       , [DimWeekOfYear] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimMonthName] CHAR(10) NULL
       , [DimMonthOfYear] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimIsLastDayOfMonth] CHAR(1) NULL
       , [DimCalendarQuarter] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimCalendarYear] SMALLINT NULL
       , [DimCalendarYearMonth] CHAR(7) NULL
       , [DimCalendarYearQtr] CHAR(7) NULL
       , [DimFiscalMonthOfYear] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimFiscalQuarter] TINYINT NULL
       , [DimFiscalYear] INT NULL
       , [DimFiscalYearMonth] CHAR(9) NULL
       , [DimFiscalYearQtr] CHAR(8) NULL
       , CONSTRAINT [DimDateIDPK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [DimDateID] )
       )
ON     [PRIMARY];
```

Comment: Please post your query

Comment: @JoeTaras I have put the query on the original post.

Comment: Are you sure your Dimtable has record (test without filter on DimDateID > (YEAR(@EndDate) * 10000)). Please post your BeginDate and EndDate values

Comment: BeginDate and EndDate can be any value of your choice - providing the EndDate isn't less than the BeginDate. I'm using 02/02/2014 and 02/02/2015 for BeginDate and EndDate respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried running SQL Server Profiler on the database and capturing the Trace when you execute the SSIS package? You should be able to see the TSQL that is being run against your database in this way.

An alternative approach to make sure that the values you are passing to the script are correct would be to place a Pre-Execute break point on the Execute SQL Task in your SSIS package and to see what the values are for each of the variables you are passing into the script.

Regards,
Christo

Comment: Definitely learn to use SQL Profiler. You'll have so many eureka moments

Comment: Thanks for that. I can see the full query execution.